# Is it possible to call std::invoke such that it can work with function pointer?

Tags: c++

If I have a class `Entity` and it has a getter function named `entityGetter` and a setter function `entitySetter`

and I wanted to apply a member function to an `Entity` object, parameterized by `value` I would do something like this

```
Entity e;
std::invoke(&Entity::entitySetter, e, someValue);
```

The idea would be equivalent to

```
    e.entitySetter(someValue);
```

---

What I want to do is make a function that further generalizes it into something like this

```
void addHelper (  int value
                , Entity& e
                , std::function<int (Entity&)> getFunc
                , std::function<void (Entity&, int)> setFunc
                ) {

  std::invoke(setFunc, e, getFunc_(value)); 

// getFunc_ returns an int. Just a wrapper around e.getFunc () * value
```

which when called somewhere with

1. a value,
2. an `Entity` object reference,
3. a getter function `getFunc` wrapped in a lambda function and
4. a setter function `setFunc` also wrapped in a lambda function

would call `getFunc_` on the object `e`, and use that value to set it in `e`.

The problem is I don't have enough experience in C++ to figure out why the above example does not work.

Comment: You're not supposed to be using `std::__invoke` _at all_! The underscores indicate this.

Comment: Look at `std::function<void (Entity&)> setFunc`.  Can that function take what needs to be set?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux  Sorry I meant to write std::invoke and not std::__invoke. Fixed the post

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes `setFunc` should take an `int`.

Comment: @atis How?  `std::function<void (Entity&)>` says it only takes an `Entity`

Comment: @NathanOliver You're right. Fixed the code.

Comment: @NathanOliver That's was the problem there! Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @NathanOliver's comment, I was able to fix the problem.

This was what I was trying before

```
void addHelper (  int value
                , Entity& e
                , std::function<int (Entity&)> getFunc
                , std::function<void (Entity&)> setFunc
                ) {

  std::invoke(setFunc, e, getFunc_(value)); 

// getFunc_ returns an int. Just a wrapper around e.getFunc () * value
```

The argument

```
std::function<void (Entity&)> setFunc
```

only takes an `Entity` object reference. Nothing to set.

It should've been defined like this

```
std::function<void (Entity&, int)> setFunc
```

so it takes an object and also a value *to set*.